# Does Object.freeze() cause the assigned object to be immutable?

Tags: javascript, object

If I write the following code:

```
var foo = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var bar = foo;
Object.freeze(bar);
```

Does this mean `foo` is also immutable?

If not, how can `bar` remain constant if `foo` is updated?

Comment: There is no object in your code (and all primitive values are immutable, yes). And if you did something like `foo = {}`, then there would be only one object (not a second "`bar` one").

Comment: note: *The object being frozen is immutable.  However, it is not necessarily constant. The second example shows that a frozen object is not constant (freeze is shallow).* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#Examples

Comment: @Bergi modified code to make my point more clear

Comment: @Fitzy Thanks. But yes, `Object.freeze` works on the (one!) *object* passed to it, not on the variable.

Comment: Btw, you should be able to simply try this out.

Comment: @Bergi I guess my question, as written in the update, is how could i change the value of `foo` without changing the value of `bar` as well?

Comment: @Fitzy Ah ok, that's what you wanted to know. See the third duplicate link for that :-)

Comment: @Bergi Sure enough, it worked. Should've been more clear. Thanks :)